# How does primitive value conversion happen in `1 + {}` and `{} + 1`?

Tags: javascript, primitive

I'm a beginner developer, and I can't understand why below statements have such outputs. Can someone explain that how/why following two expressions are interpenetrated by JavaScript differently, that their outputs are different.

```
1 + {} // => "1[object Object]"
{} + 1 // => 1
```

As `+` is a commutative operator so I was expecting same answer but it seems I am missing some language rules.

Comment: I am not a front-end developer but I know Javascript, but I don't  reason. a link will be helpful to answer it. Please give a link to read if you downvote.

Comment: you can't add an object and a number together, so neither of these would be of any practical use.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please don't vote to close as 'why isn't this code working?' the question is 'why it is working so?' that can be answered by reference to the language standard and understanding to language syntax rules.

Comment: Grijesh Chauhan, thanks for editing))

Comment: @Alexander your question is very good and valid (I think so) but because unclear asking it was down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the addition operator (+) adds the value of one numeric expression to another, or concatenates two strings.

The types of the two expressions determine the behavior of the + operator.

If both expressions are numeric or Boolean, then they are added.

```
1 + 1;
// 2

true + false;
// 1

true + true;
// 2
```

If both expressions are strings, they are concatenated:

```
"hel" + "lo";
// "hello"
```

If one expression is numeric and the other is a string they are also concatenated:

```
1 + {}
// "1[object Object]"
```

Here `[object Object]` is the string representation of `{}`:

```
String({})
// "[object Object]"
```

So hopefully the first example is clear.

However, things get weird if the first operand of `+` is an empty object literal. JavaScript interprets this as an empty code block and ignores it.

Hence, `{} + 1` is simply interpreted as `+1`, which is obviously 1.

So, why is the first `{}` interpreted as a code block? Because the complete input is parsed as a statement and curly braces at the beginning of a statement are interpreted as starting a code block.

You can fix this by forcing the input to be parsed as an expression, which then gives you the output you would expect:

```
({} + 1)
// "[object Object]1"
```

You might alike to read [this great post](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html) to find out more.

Comment: wonderful got it, though your answer add some assertions without quoting standards but conceptually interesting and helpful. big thanks!